# What Would Negative Mass Do To Spacetime?

Tags: mass, spacetime, curvature

It's known that positive mass bends space-time to create a curvature.  But if something had negative mass what would it do? Make it flat or like a crest?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass) wikipedia page will help you.

Comment: Newton's inverse-square law is equivalent to general relativity in the limit where everything is moving slowly and the gravitational field is weak. So, the first (and easiest) thing to check would be to see what happens if you plug a negative mass into Newton's gravity law. The answer, of course, is repulsive gravity. I.e. a negative mass would be repelled by ordinary matter.